# updateManifestRequestInfo & updateSegmentRequestInfo

Tags: chromecast

My Adaptive Bitrate streaming Receiver Application has a requirement to append tokens to Manifest URL & Segment URL. I came across the call back functions updateManifestRequestInfo & updateSegmentRequestInfo using which tokens to be appended can be set. 
My another requirement is that these tokens get refreshed periodically (say every 5 minutes). So, the Manifest refresh request (in case of live streaming) & Segment fetch request will have to have new tokens appended every 5 minutes.

It is not clear to me whether the above callback functions will be invoked just once after the play back has started OR before every Manifest & Segment fetch during Playback (I'll be able to implement Token refresh only if the latter is supported). 
Could you please clarify ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Those are invoked with each request.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful.